# native android scroller for 3-4 fields on 1 card does not work

Tags: livecode

I'd like to create a card with 3-4 text fields each having a native android scrollers. I followed the lesson here [Creating a native scroller to scroll a field](http://lessons.runrev.com/s/3527/m/4069/l/94412-creating-a-native-scroller-to-scroll-a-field). I tried to use the same code for another card with 3 fields that I grouped together and coded so that the group will have a native scroller. Each text field can be made visible by a separate button on that card. When opening the app the scrolling does not work. **But if I go to another card on the same stack, just empty card, and return back to the main card the scrolling works OK.** **So there is something in the card code that I don't understand and has to be amended, but what?**

I'm using this code in the card:

```
    global gScrollField
local sScrollerID
on openCard

   local tScrollerRect, tContentRect

   // Only create a scroller on a mobile device
   if environment() is not "mobile" then exit openCard

   // Set the area of the scroller
   put the rect of gScrollField into tScrollerRect

   // Set the are of the content to be scrolled
   put 0,0,(the formattedWidth of gScrollField),(the formattedHeight of gScrollField) into  tContentRect 

   // Create the scroller control
   mobileControlCreate "scroller", "loremScroll"
   put the result into sScrollerID

   // Set the properties of the scroller
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "rect", tScrollerRect
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "contentRect", tContentRect
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "visible", true
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "scrollingEnabled", true
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "vIndicator", true
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "vscroll", 0
end openCard

on closeCard
   // Delete the scroller
   if environment() is not "mobile" then exit closeCard
   mobileControlDelete sScrollerID
end closeCard

on scrollerDidScroll hOffset, vOffset
   // When the user scrolls move the displayed content
   set the vScroll of gScrollField to vOffset
end scrollerDidScroll
 mouseControl
```

and in the navigation buttons to make a field visible and hide other fields the code is (for example for card "b":

```
    global gScrollField
on mouseUp
   put the long name of fld "b" into gScrollField
   hide fld "a"
   hide fld "c"
   show fld "b"
end mouseUp
```

the link to the stack is: 
[scroll 3-4 fields on the same card](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99863601/scroll%203-4%20fields%20on%20the%20same%20card_ok%20when%20going%20back%20from%20another%20card.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problerm is that gScrollField is not defined until one of the a,b,c buttons is pressed : it initially causes the preOpenCard handler to fail.

I modified the card script to...

```
    global gScrollField
    local sScrollerID
    local sStarted

    on preOpenCard
       local tScrollerRect, tContentRect

       if sStarted <> true then
          put the long id of fld "a" into gScrollField
          hide fld "c"
          hide fld "b"
          show fld "a"
          put true into sStarted
       end if

       // Only create a scroller on a mobile device
       if environment() is not "mobile" then exit preOpenCard
       .....
       .....
       .....
```

and it works OK   :)
The sStarted variable initializes things the first time it executes.

Comment: It works great, thanks! :)  Now, since you have the stack I want to take opportunity to ask another question related to it. When I click on the Next button, the next (empty) card opens immediately. Then going back to the first card takes a while on emulator. I understand it's because on the first one there are 3 fields, buttons and code in the card. But is there anything that can be done to speed up opening of that card?

Comment: @keram - unfortunately it seems to be the amount of data in the fields that is causing the pause when navigating back to the first card.  If you put small amounts of data in the fields, it speeds up.  There's still a pause after setting acceleratedRendering to true and the test group layerMode to scrolling   :(

Comment: Should any scrolling group or field always be set to scrolling layerMode? and should acceleratedRendering always be set to true in any stack when there are scrolling groups or fields in it?